# Gnuplot automatically closes

Tags: gnuplot

I'm new in gnuplot and I'm reading a book and trying a code taught in the book "gnuplot cookbook". I ran a code from the book in gnuplot and the program shows `set x2tics -20 2` before it closes by itself. Could someone help me please why it closes and doesn't show the plot? Thanks.

I've read a code for application in gnuplot which would show two x-axes.  I've put the code in notepad, and I ran the notepad containing the code. When running the code, gnuplot shows `set x2tics -20 2` before closing on its own.

```
set x2tics -20 2
set xtics nomirror
set xrange [-10:10]
set x2range [-20:0]
plot sin(1/x) axis x1y1, 100*cos(x-1) axis x2y2
```

I expect the output to be a graph showing the two x-axes, but the actual output was a showing code of `set x2tics -20 2` then the program closes automatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work fine. Mind the comma in `set x2tics -20, 2`.

```
reset session   # reset previous settings
set xrange [-10:10] 
set xtics nomirror 
set x2range [-20:0] 
set x2tics -20, 2 
plot sin(1/x) axis x1y1, 100*cos(x-1) axis x2y2
```

Comment: You can make the plot persistent(and not close) by using the -p option.

So you can try _gnuplot -p <filenameToRun>_